# issue while importing metrics with datadog

Tags: linux, psutil, datadog, process-monitoring

i am struggling with importing metrics with datadog...I am getting below error in spite of installing all required packages...
( - instance #0 [ERROR]: Exception('You need the "psutil" package to run this check',)

request you to please help me out here as this is prove to be a major showstopper.

[root@mudcsftpup01 init.d]# ./datadog-agent info

## 2017-08-31 11:31:20,416 | INFO | dd.collector | util(util.py:481) | Pid file is: /var/run/dd-agent/dd-agent.pid

## Collector (v 4.4.0)

Status date: 2017-08-31 11:31:19 (1s ago)
  Pid: 32028
  Platform: Linux-3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-redhat-7.3-Maipo
  Python Version: 2.7.5
  Logs: , /var/log/datadog/collector.log, syslog:/dev/log

Clocks
  ======

```
NTP offset: Unknown (timed out)
System UTC time: 2017-08-31 06:01:25.512491
```

Paths
  =====

```
conf.d: /etc/dd-agent/conf.d
checks.d: /usr/share/datadog/agent/checks.d
```

Hostnames
  =========

```
socket-hostname: mudcsftpup01
hostname: mudcsftpup01
socket-fqdn: mudcsftpup01.paytm-pb.net
```

Checks
  ======

```
process
-------
  - instance #0 [ERROR]: Exception('You need the "psutil" package to run this check',)
  - instance #1 [ERROR]: Exception('You need the "psutil" package to run this check',)
  - instance #2 [ERROR]: Exception('You need the "psutil" package to run this check',)
  - instance #3 [ERROR]: Exception('You need the "psutil" package to run this check',)
  - Collected 0 metrics, 0 events & 0 service checks

tcp_check
---------
  - instance #0 [OK]
  - instance #1 [OK]
  - Collected 0 metrics, 0 events & 0 service checks

network
-------
  - instance #0 [OK]
  - Collected 0 metrics, 0 events & 0 service checks
```

Emitters
  ========

```
- http_emitter [OK]
```

## 2017-08-31 11:31:25,827 | INFO | dd.dogstatsd | util(util.py:481) | Pid file is: /var/run/dd-agent/dogstatsd.pid

## Dogstatsd (v 4.4.0)

Status date: 2017-08-31 11:31:23 (2s ago)
  Pid: 32053
  Platform: Linux-3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-redhat-7.3-Maipo
  Python Version: 2.7.5
  Logs: , /var/log/datadog/dogstatsd.log, syslog:/dev/log

Flush count: 1
  Packet Count: 0
  Packets per second: 0.0
  Metric count: 0
  Event count: 0

Answer (score 0):

Your answer appears to be there in the text -- you're missing a Python package. Try running `sudo pip install psutil`, then restarting the agent. Can you add your agent version, OS and version, and how you installed the agent to your text as well? It looks like you're also using a *very* old version of the agent (it's up to 5.17.* for a number of OS's) so there may be better package bundling or critical updates since v. 4.4.0. Try installing a newer version as well.

Answer (score -1):

Please find the required

```
[root@mudcsftpup01 ~]# sudo pip install psutil
Requirement already satisfied: psutil in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: For some reason the agent doesn't seem to be picking up your process checks -- it's hard to tell why beyond the error you've output. Check that your process.yaml file is valid in an online yaml parser. Is there anything else telling in the collector's logs? Try turning on DEBUG level logging for more info potentially: https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/204701165-How-to-get-more-logging-from-the-agent- In any event, I'd strongly suggest updating to a more recent version of the agent.

Comment: Hi -tqr_aupa_atleti

Comment: [root@mudcsftpup01 init.d]# ./datadog-agent configtest
2017-09-01 17:14:57,229 | INFO | dd.collector | util(util.py:481) | Pid file is: /var/run/dd-agent/dd-agent.pid
network.yaml is valid
tcp_check.yaml is valid
process.yaml is valid
All yaml files passed. You can now run the Datadog agent.
[root@mudcsftpup01 init.d]#    Alll the files were valid please suggest to resolve this.

Comment: The config and yaml files are not the issue here it seems. Agent 4 was not pre-packaged with dependencies so you'll have to go about manually installing them here. Are you able to upgrade the agent to a more recent version? If not, you'll have to manually install the dependencies that are required. More here on the updates with Agent 5: https://github.com/DataDog/dd-agent/wiki/Upgrade-to-Agent-5.x#what-is-datadog-agent-500 . DD strongly suggests using the most recent versions of the agent.

Comment: Hi - – tqr_aupa_atleti,

Comment: Hi - – tqr_aupa_atleti,   It seems I've did something with the python file now i"ve installed the python again but I think there is some path issue could you please suggest on this refer the error I've got.

Comment: which: nopython(/usr/lib64/q3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
* Installing YUM sources for Datadog
* Installing the Datadog Agent package
bash: /bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
bash: /bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
It looks like you hit an issue when trying to install the Agent.

Comment: I'm not sure how to resolve dependency issues dating back to Agent 4.0.X. The safest move here is to re-install the agent on this host as it is pre-bundled with those dependencies and will save you from a lot of potential issues moving forward.